# My chromium decides to start up each time I boot up computer

Tags: chromium

After installing few games from humble bundle onto my computer, I noticed my Chromium web browser started to act funny by starting up without being clicked. I reinstalled it, but the issue is not fixed. Can anyone suggest on what I can do next?
Update: I looked at Startup Applications settings and I did not find chromium there.

Answer (score 0):

Type in the dash "Startup applications" and then search for Chromium and deactivate it.

Comment: If you don't see any app or whatever you looking you should unhide all the applications by typing in a terminal `sudo sed -i "s/NoDisplay=true/NoDisplay=false/g" /etc/xdg/autostart/*.desktop` then check Startup applications again and your desired app must appear. Good luck!